# Automatically instantiate a NativeScript plugin on import?

Tags: typescript, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I create a NativeScript plugin. I would like the plugin to be instantiated when it is imported. Is it possible ? If I think badly, is there another way?

```
// A message should appear in the console
import * example from "example";

// The message appears in the console because the plugin is imported
```

Comment: That depends on what your plugin does. For example, you could take a look at nativescript-platform-css / nativescript-orientation plugins, those does the job upon import statement, they actually do not need an instance. You could design your plugin as a singleton.

Comment: Thank you very much @Manoj ! Import the plugin with the event of the launched application works perfectly well.